# Crystal formula for displaying varbinary image data in the report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, imagefield

I have a table used in a stored procedure, in the database which has two columns. One is 'signature' (`varbinary` datatype) which is an image and the other is 'name' (`varchar` datatype).

I want to display the signature on the Crystal report, but if it's not present in the database, I want to display the name instead. Can someone help me with a formula because the formula that I have mentioned below does not work.

```
IF {rpt_SP_for_signature;1.signature} <> "" THEN
   {rpt_SP_for_signature;1.signature} 
ELSE {rpt_SP_for_signature;1.name}
```

This throws this error:

> A blob field cannot be used in a formula

Comment: *an error* - ***what*** error?!?!?!? Remember: we cannot see or read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you have to **SHOW US** so we have any chance of helping you!

Comment: My apologies, Marc!  the error is 'A blob field cannot be used in a formula'.

Comment: Does anything print on the report when there is no signature image?  If the answer is no, then no need to use a formula to suppress anything, just place the name field behind the image field.  Then when an image is present, it will cover the name field, but when there is no image it will reveal the name field.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, R. McMillan! I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Hey, R. McMillan, this trick was super cool and it worked! Thanks and have a great day ahead!